Filtering Array on API Request with Strapi [Multiselect]
`Hi everyone,
I am trying to build a request with Strapi filtering the json response, depending on a string contained in an array of options. Here is the Json :
{ "data": [ { "id": 2, "attributes": { "selectTheTitleView": "Column_3_View", "selectUserRoles": [ "ALL" ], "selectSubChannels": [ "Elite" ] } }, { "id": 5, "attributes": { "selectTheTitleView": "Column_3_View", "selectUserRoles": [ "TM-SUPERVISOR" ], "selectSubChannels": [ "Sparc" ] } }, { "id": 4, "attributes": { "selectTheTitleView": "Column_3_View", "selectUserRoles": [ "BRM-SUPERVISOR", "TM-SUPERVISOR", "VERTICAL-HEAD-SUPERVISOR" ], "selectSubChannels": [ "Sparc" ] } }, { "id": 3, "attributes": { "selectTheTitleView": "Column_3_View", "selectUserRoles": [ "PRODUCER" ], "selectSubChannels": [ "S2S" ] } } ], "meta": { "pagination": { "page": 1, "pageSize": 25, "pageCount": 1, "total": 4 } } }
I am trying to create a request that says : Please send me all the catalogs for which the “selectUserRoles” equals to “PRODUCER”.
Here is the requests i have tried so far :
http://localhost:1337/api/supplier-catalogs?filters/[selectUserRoles][$in][0]=PRODUCER
http://localhost:1337/api/supplier-catalogs?filters/[selectUserRoles][$in]=PRODUCER
http://localhost:1337/api/supplier-catalogs?filters/[selectUserRoles][$eq]=PRODUCER
but it's not working .Please help`

What is the field type that you used for the selectUserRoles attribute?

I have used Multiselect field.

@JimLAURIE I have used Multiselect field.

here is the answer of your question.
It looks like you are using a multi-select field.
This is not a native field that you have in Strapi - so not directly supported by the Strapi team.
Here is plugin that you probably installed: https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-multi-select
Based on the code base (developed by a community member), I can see that they store the content as a JSON:
https://github.com/Zaydme/strapi-plugin-multi-select/blob/main/server/register.js
And you can't filter via Strapi default filters on the JSON type.
You will have to follow the code from that answer:
Is there a way to filter json data format field in strapi?
Create a dedicated route/controller to filter manually with the filter on the JSON object (thanks to the query system)

I encountered the same problem using the MultiSelect and trying to filter it.
filters[facilities][$containsi]=WiFI

Only containsi works for me, and I will keep it around for the moment but I expect it to be quite inefficient for large data volumes so I will look into writing a custom implementation sooner or later.
